# Oracle query on time (and not date)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

How can you query on just the time portion of an Orace date field. Ie:

```
select * from mytable 
where 
date_column < '05:30:00'
```

Want the query to return any rows where the time represented by date_column is less than 5:30 regardless of the date.

Comment: It's a DATE column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select * from mytable 
where 
to_char( date_column, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) < '05:30:00'
```

Comment: alex's answer also works but this is the easiest to follow imho thanks.

Comment: Just keep in mind that what you are doing is string comparison, not time or date. As long as you use 24 hour format, string comparison should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how far the date is from midnight, and filter on that:

```
select * from mytable 
where date_column - trunc(date_column) < 5.5/24
```

The `date_column - trunc(date_column)` calculation will give you a fraction of a day, as is normal for [date arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref170). The `5.5/24` is the fraction of the day represented by the time at 05:30; 5.5 hours out of 24 hours.

If the column was a timestamp instead of a date you'd see an interval data type as the result of the subtraction. You can use [an interval literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#i38598) anyway if you prefer or find it easier to understand than 5.5/24 (or have more complicated times to compare, which are harder to express as a fraction):

```
select * from mytable 
where date_column < trunc(date_column) + interval '0 05:30:00' day to second;
```

This way round you're comparing the date in your column with the truncated date (i.e. midnight on that day) with 5 hours 30 minutes added to it, which is 05:30 the same day.

Quick demo with simple data in a CTE, and a third very slight variant, but they all get the same result:

```
with mytable (date_column) as (
  select to_date('2016-04-15 05:29:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('2016-04-14 05:29:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select to_date('2016-04-15 05:30:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select * from mytable 
where date_column < trunc(date_column) + 5.5/24;

DATE_COLUMN       
-------------------
2016-04-15 05:29:29
2016-04-14 05:29:29
```

Note though that any manipulation of the column like this will prevent an index being used. If you have to do this regularly it might be worth adding a virtual column/index which does that calculation.

Comment: @MarcusLeon - that's not very helpful. What happens when you run it?  What raw data do you have, what result do you expect, what do you get? (Adding the first two to the question might be useful). I've just checked with some test data and it brings back rows where the time is before 05:30 on any date.

Comment: too hard
to_char( date_column, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) < '05:30:00' looks simple

Comment: @PavelZimogorov - not sure why it's hard, it's just simple maths. String comparison makes me nervous, though it's safe with the `HH24` mask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the time back to date, otherwise you're simply doing string comparison. 
Oracle doesn't really have a clever way of doing this. Simplest to cast both dates to the same day and do the comparison.

I.e.

```
select *
  from mytable
 where to_date ('01.01.2000 ' || to_char (date_column, 'hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <
          to_date ('01.01.2000' || '05:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```